# Is there an equivalent to Python's enumerate() for .NET IEnumerable

Tags: .net, ienumerable

I could not find a related question.

In `python` you can easily loop through a sequence (`list`, `generator` etc) and collect the index of the iteration at the same time thanks to `enumerate(seq)` like this :

```python
>>> for (i,item) in enumerate(["toto","titi","tutu"]):
...     print i, item
...
0 toto
1 titi
2 tutu
```

Is there something similar for IEnumerable, that would, for instance, transform a `IEnumerable<T>` in a `IEnumerable<Tuple<Int32,T>>` ?

(I know it would be easily done thanks to the correct function in `Select()` .. but if it exists, I'd rather use it :) )

**UPDATE**
FYI, I am curious about this kind of possibility to be able to do something like : "give me the index of the last item that fulfils this condition", which would then be accomplished through :

```
myEnumeration.First(t => some condition on t.Item2 ... ).Item1;
```

Comment: Maybe adding this for completeness. Here is a way using desconstruct : https://twitter.com/buhakmeh/status/1291029712458911752?s=20

Comment: Also just discovered https://twitter.com/SergioPedri/status/1291330327881879552?s=20 . `Microsoft.Toolkit.HighPerformance` has a 'Enumerate()' extension method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using a `Tuple<,>` (which is a class) you can use a `KeyValuePair<,>` which is a struct. This will avoid memory allocations when enumerated (not that they are very expensive, but still).

```c#
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, T>> Enumerate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) {
    return items.Select((item, key) => new KeyValuePair(key, item));
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is actually what I am using right now, but it feels a bit awkward (specially when written in VB.NET ... but what code involving generics in VB.NET looks nice ? )

Comment: to illustrate :
`Dim lastAccountDiscountIndex = availableDiscounts.Select(Function(d, i) New KeyValuePair(Of GlobalDiscountDefaultValue, Int32)(d, i)) _
                                           .Last(Function(kvp) kvp.Key.Source.Type = GlobalDiscountSourceType.QuotationAccount) _
                                           .Value`

Comment: Well, don't use VB.NET then ;) - I know that this isn't very constructive, but VB.NET has major syntax shortcomings IMHO in generics. BTW, as of .NET 4, the [`_` line combining character is no longer required in all cases](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-vb-2010-enhancements/), you should be able to at least drop those.

Comment: I wish I had a choice :'( . Actually I can not drop those underscores in that case . I could if I wanted to keep the dot at the end of each line, and the Method on the following one, but it just looks wrong to me ...

Comment: Yeah, I though so (that you didn't have the choice). Anyways, I'd prefer the dot at the end of the line (which is my style anyways *g*) compared to the continuation character and the dot at the beginning of the line. Sorry for not being more helpful.

Comment: I'll mark this one as the answer for the comment about KeyValuePair vs Tuple.

Answer (score 15):

C# 7 finally allows you to do this in an elegant way:

```c#
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<(int, T)> Enumerate<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> input,
        int start = 0
    )
    {
        int i = start;
        foreach (var t in input)
            yield return (i++, t);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new string[]
        {
            "Alpha",
            "Bravo",
            "Charlie",
            "Delta"
        };

        foreach (var (i, o) in s.Enumerate())
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}: {o}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As for a specific function that will do what you're asking, I don't know if .NET includes it. The quickest way, however, would just be to do something like this:

```c#
int id = 0;
foreach(var elem in someList)
{
    ... doStuff ...
    id++;
}
```

EDIT: Here is a function that will do as you ask, using `yield return`, but it has the downside of requiring one GC allocation per iteration:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, T>> Enumerate<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    int id = 0;
    foreach(var elem in list)
    {
        yield return new Tuple<int, T>(id, elem);
        id++;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `yield` return which, I assume, is the same as returning something in the function in the `Select()` method. (see my answer below, the incrementing of index is done for you in one of the signatures of `Select()`)

Comment: I'll mark the one with KeyValuePair as the answer because of the struct vs class thing. But thanks for this one :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is my own answer to my own question ...

If it does not exist, I might as well do it like that, without actually writing a `for`/`foreach` :

```c#
var items = new List<String> { "toto", "titi", "tutu" };

var enumerated = items.Select((x, i) => new Tuple<int, String>(i, x));

foreach (var t in enumerated)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} : {1}", t.Item1, t.Item2));

}
```

which prints:

```
0 : toto
1 : titi
2 : tutu
```

It's a one-liner ... an ugly one, but a one-liner anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension method, that will return sequence of tuples, where the first item is number in a sequence and the second item is the value from the source sequence.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, T>> Enumerate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int start = 0)
{
    return source.Select((value, index) => new Tuple<int, T>(index + start, value));
}
```

Examples:

```
var source = new[] { "apple", "pear", "banana", "orange", "lemon" };
var enumerated1 = source.Enumerate();   // { (0, "apple"), (1, "pear"), (2, "banana"), (3, "orange"), (4, "lemon") }
var enumerated2 = source.Enumerate(3);  // { (3, "apple"), (4, "pear"), (5, "banana"), (6, "orange"), (7, "lemon") }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Zip` with `Enumerable.Range`?

```
var list = new List<string> { "toto", "titi", "tutu" };
foreach (var (str, i) in list.Zip(Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + " " + str);
}
```

Output:

```
0 toto
1 titi
2 tutu
```